# Bootstrap CSS messing up community template

Tags: napili, bootstrap, lightning-community

I'm developing some lightning components for the Napili template, but adding bootstrap css to the component and adding it to the template interferes with its styling. I read a couple of articles about namespacing my components, I'm not working on a developer org and cannot set the namespace.

How can I avoid affecting the Napili template's styling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can de-scope the bootstrap from entire Napili Template. Instead apply for specific sections.

This can be done using [Less.js](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/wiki/GUI-compilers-that-use-LESS.js)

```
.bootstrap-div {
    //put the bootstrap @includes here
}
```

so

```
<div class="bootstrap-div"> 
   Bootstrap works here
</div>

<div>
  No bootstrap
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a detailed guide to expand on this point: https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap